# Imprimir todas as fotos em uma pasta com batch

Tags: windows, batch

Olá, estou tentando fazer um batch que imprima todos os arquivos de uma pasta, porem na fila da impressão aparece "documento de nivel inferior local" e no status aparece "Erro - imprimindo"
O que poderá ser? Segue o meu codigo:

```
@echo OFF 
net use LPT2: /delete /yes
net use LPT2: \\FELIPE-PC\pdf  /yes
cls
@echo %time%
dir *.jpg > LPT2:
```

Comment: Achei essa solução interessante, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634776/batch-multiple-image-printing-on-single-sheet, veja se te ajuda.